message queuing using chat program ( C )
I want to create a simple chat program using message queuing. The language used is C or C++. The development environment is visual studio.
I created a personal cue, entered the cue name in the code below, and ran the code, but the code couldn't find the cue.
The message queue was created as a personal queue through computer management. This is my first time coding related to MSMQ, so I have not added libraries or managed the environment related to the code.
type here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define QUEUE_NAME "\\rammimmi\\private$\\test"

void receiveMessage() {
    HANDLE hQueue;
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    char szBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];


    hQueue = CreateFile(QUEUE_NAME, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hQueue == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error opening the queue. Exiting.\n");
        return;
    }


    while (1) {
        if (ReadFile(hQueue, szBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) {
            szBuffer[dwBytesRead] = '\0';
            printf("Received message: %s\n", szBuffer);
        }
    }


    CloseHandle(hQueue);
}

void sendMessage(const char* message) {
    HANDLE hQueue;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;


    hQueue = CreateFile(QUEUE_NAME, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hQueue == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error opening the queue. Exiting.\n");
        return;
    }


    if (!WriteFile(hQueue, message, strlen(message), &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
        printf("Error sending message.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Message sent: %s\n", message);
    }


    CloseHandle(hQueue);
}

int main() {
    char message[BUFFER_SIZE];

    printf("MSMQ Chat Program\n");
    printf("Type a message and press Enter to send.\n");


    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)receiveMessage, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating receive thread.\n");
        return 1;
    }


    while (1) {
        gets(message);
        if (strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        sendMessage(message);
    }


    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}



I don't mind rewriting this entire code, so please let me know how to solve it.
When I run the code, it runs, but it says 'Error opening the queue.' Exiting.' This is a situation where an error message is displayed. I think it's a situation where I entered the cue name in the code, but the personal cue I created wasn't recognized, or the personal cue I created is wrong.
Thanks for your quick advice. There were many shortcomings in posting questions using different languages.

Please don't tag or mention multiple different languages, unless the question really is about all those languages. You seem to be programming in C, and only C. So you should only tag and mention C.

On a different note, whatever resource you use that taught you to use gets, you should throw it away. The gets function is so dangerous it has even been removed from the C language. Use fgets instead.

And where do you create the queue? How do you create it? Doesn't special names and paths in Windows usually use double leading back-slashes, so you need e.g. "\\\\rammimmi\\private$\\test"?

I don't code for windows so this may be all wrong... But it seems to me that "OPEN_EXISTING" may be a problem. The "receiveMessage" thread may run before the "main" thread creates the file. Perhaps moving "CreateFile" so it's done before "CreateThread" could help.
